# Limit on use of Facebook API

Tags: facebook-apps

Is there any limit or fee to use the Facebook API? Can I develop a commercial software app with the Facebook API?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713241/whats-the-facebooks-graph-api-call-limit

Answer (score 4):

This is best answered already [on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713241/whats-the-facebooks-graph-api-call-limit):

> [According to Facebook dev policies "I. Features and Functionality"](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) the
>   only limits are:
>
> ```
> (>5M MAU) or (>100M API calls per day) or (>50M impressions per day).
> ```
>
> (Mau means monthly users)

and

> The best answer to this question from another [forum](http://www.quora.com/Whats-the-Facebook-Open-Graph-API-rate-limit#)
>
> "After some testing and discussion with the Facebook platform team,
>   there is no official limit I'm aware of or can find in the
>   documentation. However, I've found 600 calls per 600 seconds, per
>   token & per IP to be about where they stop you. I've also seen some
>   application based rate limiting but don't have any numbers

You can develop commercial software with the API, read the [dev policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) for more details. If you exceed the limits above you'll probably have to pay.